# Text Based Game, picking items up

Tags: python

I have been working on this project for a week now, I have looked all over the internet, tried different methods and nothing seems to work. My program is for a game moving between rooms and collecting items to defeat a boss. I have the movement down, I have ending the game down but I cannot pick items up and store them in my inventory. I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Here is what I have so far.

```
rooms = {'Entrance Hall': {'name': 'Entrance Hall', 'west': 'Loft', 'item': 'no items'},
         'Loft': {'name': 'Loft', 'north': 'Dining Room', 'east': 'Entrance Hall', 'item': 'sword'},
         'Dining Room': {'name': 'Dining room', 'west': 'Study', 'east': 'Bedroom', 'north': 'Apothecary', 'south': 'Loft', 'item': 'garlic'},
         'Study': {'name': 'Study', 'east': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'scroll'},
         'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'west': 'Dining Room', 'north': 'Living Room', 'item': 'torch'},
         'Living Room': {'name': 'Living Room', 'south': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'boots'},
         'Apothecary': {'name': 'Apothecary', 'south': 'Dining Room', 'east': 'Basement', 'item': 'potion'},
         'Basement': {'name': 'Basement', 'west': 'Apothecary', 'item': 'no item'}
         }
#defining game instrucions
def game_instructions():
    print('Welcome to the Dracula game')
    print('You have traveled to Draculas mansion to put an end to his terror')
    print('You will need to collect 6 items around his mansion to be able to defeat him and win')
    print('If you go into the basement without the 6 items, you lose')
    print('Move commands: north, south, east and west')
    print('When moving to a new room if there is an item, type "get" to pick it up or leave behind')

def user_status():
    print('\n ------------------------')
    print('You are currently in the {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('In this room you see a {}' .format(current_room['item']))
    print('Inventory: ', inventory)
    print('\n ------------------------')


def get_item(current_room, user_input, rooms, inventory):
    inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
    del rooms[current_room]['item']

#setting directions to the variables
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
#starting room
current_room = rooms['Entrance Hall']
#calling on game instructions
game_instructions()
inventory = []


# Starting game loop
continue_loop = True
while continue_loop:
    if current_room['name'] == 'Basement':
        if len(inventory) == 6:
            print('You have collected all the items and defeated dracula')
            print('Thank you for playing')
        else:
            print('You have not collected all the items and dracula was too strong')
            print('You lose, thanks for playing')
        continue_loop = False
    else:
        user_status()
        # Displaying current room
       # print('You are currently in the {}.'.format(current_room['name']))

        # getting user direction
        user_input = input('\nWhich direction would you like to go?')
        # deciding where to go based on input
        if user_input in directions:
            if user_input in current_room:
                current_room = rooms[current_room[user_input]]#moving player to new room if input is valid
            else:
                # input was not in specific rooms directions
                print('You cannot go that way.')
        if len(user_input) == 4 and user_input == 'get' and s.join(user_input[1:3]) in rooms[current_room]['item']:
            print('You pick up {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
            get_item()
            continue
        # input was not valid, not in move commands
        else:
            print('Invalid input')
            continue
```

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news), but not for questions about games written with python.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide the right arguments to the `get_item` function:

```
get_item(current_room, "get", rooms, inventory)
```

Note also that the second argument of such function is useless since it is not used in the function body, you can remove it from the function definition and not provide it in the function call.

As a side note, it is not really clear what variable `s` in the last`if` condition refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems:
As mentioned already, you are not passing arguments to the get_item() function.
Also as mentioned above it seems that get_item() receives redundant arguments, and also the usage of current_room is confusing there (since in the main loop it represents an object and you use it as a string inside get_item().

`def get_item(current_room, inventory)` should be enough.
since `current_room` already points to the object representing the whole room.

In addition it seems like the expected user input for picking up items is `get <item name>`.
therefore I suggest a condition like:

```
if user_input[0:3] == 'get':
  if user_input[4:] in rooms[current_room]['item'] and user_input[4:] != 'no item':
    get_item(current_room, inventory)
  else:
    print('Item does not exist in the room')
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your feedback I have tried using the above statement inside my code but still not picking items up, i dont know if im just not grasping the concept or what, sorry and thank you again.

Comment: try to debug your code by adding print() commands and print the variable values and try to find the exact spot where thing dont behave like you expected. I would try to print inside the get_item() function and check if it behaves as you expected